# Update KendoUI Grid datasource with new items

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have:

```
$.post('buying-grid/split/' + config.route.params.id, item).success(function(data){
                var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource();
                ds.data(data)
                $('#buyingGrid').data('kendoGrid').setDataSource(ds)
                $('#buyingGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.sync();
            })
```

But I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

The data variable is in the correct format of `{"data":[{"id":99296,...`

Why is this not working?

Comment: which line are you getting the error for? doesn't look like it's in that snippet; also: data should be an array

Comment: @LarsHöppner it was for ds.data, it wasn't an array instead I should have passed data.data, not just data. +1

Comment: posted as an answer so you can close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `ds.data(data)`, data has to be an array of items. Your server backend is probably returning a response object that has the array in `data.data`, so you need to call:

```
ds.data(data.data);
```